# PHP function for select element - display non existent values

Tags: php

i have created this function in PHP to display values in a select element

```
if(!function_exists("StatusSelect")) {
    function StatusSelect($selected = array(), $type, $behaviour = '') {
        global $mysqli;

        $val = '';
        $ret = '';

        $list = Statuses($type, $behaviour);
        foreach($list["results"] as $item) {
            $ret.= '<option value="'.$item["name"].'"';
            if(in_array($item["name"], $selected) or $item["default"] == 'Y') {
                $ret.= ' selected="selected"';
            }
            $ret.= '>'.($item["display"] ? $item["display"] : $item["name"]).'</option>';
        }

        return $ret;
    }
}
```

it calls a function called `Statuses` which returns a loop of items

so i call this function like:

```
echo '<select name="status" class="form-control required">';
echo StatusSelect(array('1'), "test");
echo '</select>';
```

and its working fine and putting the correct value as `selected` but i want a way to still display a value if it no longer exists in the loop but its included in the `$selected` array

so as an example, if i had the following values:

```
1
2
3
4
```

that are returned in my loop when calling the `Statuses` function

and a value of `5` is in the `$selected` array

i want the element to look like:

```
<select name="status" class="form-control required">
<option value="5" selected>5</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

but currently it would just be:

```
<select name="status" class="form-control required">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
```

`Statuses` function:

```
function Statuses($type, $behavior='') {
    global $conn;

    $results=array();
    $sql="SELECT * from statuses where type = '".$type."' ";
    if($behavior != '') {
        $sql.="and behavior = '".$behavior."' ";
    }
    $sql.="ORDER by list_order, name ASC ";
    $rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn);
    while($result=mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
        $results[] = $result;
    }
    return array("results" => $results);
}
```

Comment: Can you show an example of what it should look like and what it looks like now?

Comment: Can you show your `Statuses()`?

Comment: the function you want to see?

Comment: yep, the function's body

Comment: sure, see update again

Comment: It kinda depends if any missing item that is in `$selected` but not in the `$list` should be shown at the end or in order (like value 3 is missing in `$list` but in `$selected` and `$list` goes to 6 or so). Than you could maybe combine both arrays to one and loop just over that? If not than just loop over the `$selected` at the end and append them. Maybe you can give some further information about how this should look like.

Comment: it would be good to have the selected but non existent option at the top

Comment: @charlie, check this out =)

Comment: i use this function all over my site at the moment so dont really want to change it

Comment: its only the `Statuses` function that is currently used, the `StatusSelect` function is new

Comment: @charlie, check update

Answer (score 0):

You can change your function `Statuses($type, $behaviour)` to something like this:

```
function Statuses($type, $behavior='', $selected = null) {
    global $conn;

    $results=array();
    $sql="SELECT * from statuses where type = '".$type."' ";
    if($behavior != '') {
        $sql.="and behavior = '".$behavior."' ";
    }
    $sql.="ORDER by list_order, name ASC ";
    $rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn);
    while($result=mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
        $results[] = $result;
    }
    if (null !== $selected && is_array($selected)) {
        foreach($selected as $val) {
            $results[] = array('name' => $val, 'default' => 'N', 'display' => $val);
        }
    }
    return array("results" => $results);
}
```

Or, you can change your `StatusSelect()`, like this:

```
function StatusSelect($selected = array(), $type, $behaviour = '') {
    global $mysqli;

    $val = '';
    $ret = '';

    $list = Statuses($type, $behaviour);
    $found = false;
    foreach($list["results"] as $item) {
        $ret.= '<option value="'.$item["name"].'"';
        if(in_array($item["name"], $selected) or $item["default"] == 'Y') {
            $found = true;
            $ret.= ' selected="selected"';
        }
        $ret.= '>'.($item["display"] ? $item["display"] : $item["name"]).'</option>';
    }
    if (!$found) {
        foreach($selected as $val) {
            $ret = '<option value="' . $val . '" selected="selected">' . $val . '</option>' . $ret;
        }
    }

    return $ret;
 }
```

[tested](http://tehplayground.com/#8984eJQ6W) =). Outputs:

```
<option value="5" selected="selected">5</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
```

Comment: @charlie, btw, does your `$selected` array can contain more than one element?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating an intermediate function that will update the `$list` with values from `$selected` and then send it over to generate html:

```
<?php

function Statuses($type, $behaviour) {
    // just return some static data:
    return array(
        "results" => 
        array(
            array("name" => "1", "default" => "N"),
            array("name" => "2", "default" => "N"),
            array("name" => "3", "default" => "N"),
            array("name" => "4", "default" => "N"),
        ),
   );
}

// read Statuses() and update with synthetic values from $selected
function StatusesWithSelected($type, $behaviour, $selected) {
    $statuses = Statuses($type, $behaviour);
    $newStatuses = array_diff($selected, array_map(function($x){return $x["name"];}, $statuses["results"]));
    foreach ($newStatuses as $s){
        $statuses["results"][] = array(
            "name" => $s,
            "default" => "Y",
            );
    }
    return $statuses;
}
if(!function_exists("StatusSelect")) {
    function StatusSelect($selected = array(), $type, $behaviour = '') {
        global $mysqli;

        $val = '';
        $ret = '';

        $list = StatusesWithSelected($type, $behaviour, $selected);
        foreach($list["results"] as $item) {
            $ret.= '<option value="'.$item["name"].'"';
            if($item["default"] == 'Y') {
                $ret.= ' selected="selected"';
            }
            $ret.= '>'.(isset($item["display"]) ? $item["display"] : $item["name"]).'</option>'; // I added isset here to prevent Notices
        }

        return $ret;
    }
}

echo StatusSelect(array('4', '5'), "test");
```

[Tested](http://tehplayground.com/#759J2Nw4r). Output:

```
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5" selected="selected">5</option>
```